# Design an $O(n)$ deterministic algorithm to find the approximate median of an array

Tags: statistics, algorithms

We have an unordered sequence $A$ which consists of $n$ different numbers $A[1],A[2],A[3],\dots, A[n]$.

One member of $A$ is named an approximate median if $A$ contains at least $n/4$ members smaller than $x$ and at least $n/4$ members bigger than $x$.

How to design a deterministic algorithm than finds all approximate medians in time $O(n)$?

Comment: He didn't say they are ordered, just that they are different.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you I think I misunderstood the term "ordered sequence".

Comment: So, the OP should clarify, because what he means is not clear.

Comment: If the sequence is already ordered, then it's just a question of picking out the middle elements of the array. Otherwise, is an average-time solution acceptable? If so, (hint:) the standard solution is a variant of quicksort. And there are even (non-obvious) ways to optimize the pivot selection to give guaranteed linear run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a celebrated algorithm finding the (exact) median in linear time. By adding dummy elements, the algorithm can be used to find the $k$th largest element in linear time (in fact, the algorithm is already stated so that it finds the $k$th largest element for an arbitrary $k$). Find the $n/4$th largest element and $n/4$th smallest element in linear time. One pass through the array will then find all approximate medians.

Comment: Can you add pseudocode for that?

Comment: That's your job. We don't solve the exercise for you, we help you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really ordered then it is trivial.  Otherwise it is not trivial but you can still do it in O(n) using something like the implementation of [nth_element()](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/nth-element.html).

Comment: I was thinking using selection algorithm in this. Can you explain a  bit more?

Comment: @pressy: a naive selection algorithm to solve this problem is slower than linear; the linear nth_element algorithm is more like the celebrated exact median algorithm mentioned by yuval and may be thought of as its generalization.